# Jenkins how to deploy same code to different servers (that I can specify)?

Tags: docker, jenkins, deployment, containers

in the software company I work we use jenkins to deploy to different servers, the way we do that is ever single branch from git repository deploy to the specific server based on the name of the branch and in the specifications on the jenkinsfile. But we are in the process of unification of this branchs in just one: Master, but how we can configure jenkins to catch the same code and deploy to the servers we are interested in, without changing the code? I think we should separate code from deploy, but the pipeline still have to exist in some way.

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions come to mind:

1. I believe you may be using SCM polling to get the builds started. With git diff you can check what was changed and based on that start the specific deployment.
2. If you are running the builds manually you can parameterize the build and specify this way which one you want to deploy.

From experience you might want to set the pipeline so when you commit to the repository only testing and building is done and deploy is not done (or only on a test env) and the proper prod deploy is done only manually (and can be parameterized).